# Google Analytics reports all real-time views, but doesn't reflect in overview fully

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, real-time

My analytics was working normally, when suddenly in the middle of the day it stopped recording almost all pageviews/sessions in the overview and general views. Tracking works normally, everything showing in real-time views. There are no filters and UID is not turned on.

Everything is showing in real-time, but it records the views only partially in the overview (for example instead of 200 it records only 30).

It is a big problem as it's always instant and important if you get paid for ads daily.  I am not a developer either, so cannot dig deep here. Thanks.

Comment: Does the missing data ever appear?   If you check the next day, has the data for the previous day been corrected?

Comment: Data appeared only for 1 day, but not for the other day before that. I guess I will never figure out what happened on that day...

Comment: There is an App Status Dashboard (which i had completely forgotten about) that will show when GA (and other apps) may have known, problems. GA is in the lower portion of the page, if you click it, it will take you to further info about the issue https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status

Comment: Thank you so much @BronwynV , I did not know about the status dashboard. It shows that there was a problem on those 2 days. Thanks again, you are a star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is showing in real time reports, then it is likely a normal standard intraday data processing delay.
While you will often get data on the same day with little delay it's not guaranteed. 24-48hrs data processing delay is considered normal for daily standard reporting

[image]

Ref: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084038?hl=en

There are also data limits that can also slow down intra day reporting:

> Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to
>   Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day.
>   This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To
>   restore intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your
>   account sends to < 200,000 per day.

Ref: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en

Also be aware there is an App Status Dashboard that will show when GA (and other apps) may have known, widespread, problems. Seems GA did have a short service disruption over the 12/16-17 period.
https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=18&iid=ee0c031909bd430a733bb33b69ba8350